# using WPF+OpenGLin 2 thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, opengl

is it safe to use ِِDirectX and OpenGl in two thread with 2 independent window?an application with WPF and OpenGL crash randomly.the last thing that I am suspicious of it is safety of multithreading OpenGL and WPF.

Comment: Two independent windows? Sure... they will both have their own render context. You can never have more than one thread accessing the same render context in OpenGL, the window system literally does not allow you to create such a situation. So thread safety is not a big issue in GL, the bigger issue is actually the ***extra work*** you have to do to get resources loaded in one thread to work with another one, since you have to use a separate render context per-thread. You have to use context resource sharing to achieve this, which is an additional initialization step.

Comment: my question is about two thread one DX(WPF is DX based ) and another OpenGL. the application randomly crash at OpenGL driver function like nvogl64.DrvCreateContext, nvogl64.DrvPresentBuffers, I haven't  any idea about it.there is no opengl error when i debug it with gDebugger.